# How do I get my page to render like when developer tools are showing?

Tags: debugging, browser, cross-browser, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Both Chrome and Firefox render my page and respond to window page resizes the way I want when the developer tools are up but not when they are not.

Debugger present - note that content is centered.
[image: Page viewed with debugger]

Dubugger closed - content is now wider than the window.
[image: Page when viewed without debugger]
HTML from VS Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>Karl Mochel's Work Experience</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ce8498ab41.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="src\gallery.js"></script>
    <link href="sass/style_test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="top_navbar">
        <div class="name">
            Karl Mochel
        </div>
        <div>
            <nav class="nav basic">
                <a href="#" class="active">Work</a>
                <a href="values.html">Values</a>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="name balance">kalmdesigns</div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS from VS Code

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather");
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Merriweather", "Times", serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  color: #d3e0ee;
  background-color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
  min-width: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a {
  color: #7cbbff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #B6C1CC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #7cbbff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-inline: max(20px, 50% - 450px);
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.top_navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  background: #B6C1CC;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.top_navbar .name {
  font-family: "Oswald", "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
  line-height: 3rem;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.top_navbar .name a {
  color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
}
.top_navbar .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: "Oswald", "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
}
.top_navbar .nav a {
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
}
.top_navbar .nav a:visited {
  color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
}
.top_navbar .nav a:hover {
  color: #5f90c2;
}
.top_navbar .nav a.active {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.top_navbar .close {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.top_navbar .close .fa-xmark {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
}
.top_navbar .close .fa-xmark:hover {
  color: #5f90c2;
}

.top_navbar {
  align-items: baseline;
}
.top_navbar .basic {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.top_navbar .company {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.top_navbar .company .bc_work > a {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
.top_navbar .company .bc_icon {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: rgb(44, 62, 77);
}
.top_navbar .company .bc_company {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
.top_navbar .balance {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Using Chrome Version 110.0.5481.104 (Official Build) (64-bit), Firefox 110.0 (64-bit)

Comment: This is caused by something in your CSS, so the question needs an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: My CSS is a few hundred lines. If I could easily get the problem to happen in an MCVE then I likely would be able to find the problem. This question is for someone who has strategic debugging experience and can point me in a direction to look.

Comment: A few hundred lines is nothing scary, really. While it may be too much for a typical question on StackOverflow, but that's better than having an unanswerable question being closed for the lack of MCVE. As for strategic debugging experience, making an MCVE is the first step to solve the problem in practically every case. The rest are solved by divide-and-conquer.

Comment: The question is not unanswerable. An acceptable answer is "look at where you might have used X or Y in your CSS or set Y in your browser, or something else (that is quickly testable)" which will take more research on my side but reduce the scope of research by a factor. There is value in SO providing direction (teaching debugging skills) instead of completely solving problems, even if a specific solution isn't provided. I would totally upvote an answer that helped me debug faster.

Comment: That's just a rule of the thumb: almost all questions without MCVE about a nontrivial problem are unanswerable or require an inordinate amount of time guessing. Making MCVE is the first strategic debugging step anyone should make, which is why it is required in the rules. I've tried the HTML/CSS you added but it only shows a few text labels. Try saving the HTML/CSS from a live page.

Comment: The code above was the SCSS. I replaced it this time with the CSS.

I have saved off a live page and some extensions like Grammarly inject things into it. I have run the page with the extensions disabled and the page acts the same.

Comment: The problem is caused by `min-width: 100vh`, which looks like a typo instead of `100vw` or otherwise incorrect assumption about width/height ratio. Looking at your screenshot now I see the scrollbar, so indeed someone with more experience in CSS could have spotted it without an MCVE.

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem without having the dev tools up. Would like to know why the dev tools acted differently and rendered as I desired....

You need to make it an answer so I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused the typo **min-width: 100vh**, instead of **100vw**, in the *body* descriptor.

While this solves the problem for normal display this doesn't explain why when  Developer Tools is active the page acts like the min-width was 100vw...